# C# XML Select dictionary node by key value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, itunes, xmldocument

I have an XML file (It's an iTunes file) with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
        <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
        <key>Application Version</key><string>12.3.3.17</string>

    ...

        <key>Music Folder</key><string>file://localhost/C:/Users/username/longpath/</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

How can I get the value of the last string, where the `<key>` is 'Music Folder'?

It's a really big file, so I'd rather not iterate through all the nodes.

I've tried some of the following:

```
XmlNode location = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("descendant::dict[key='Music Folder']");
location = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//text()[.='Music Folder']");
location = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("string[last()]");
location = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("dict::string[last()]");
location = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("descendant::dict[string[last()]]");
```

I'm not that familiar with XPath expressions and having trouble making the correct expression.

I'm open to LINQ solutions too.

Comment: If Music folder is always last, would `/plist/dict//key[last()]/text()` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath expression for your document is evaluated in the context of the document root so you need to specify the `plist` node ideally, and I assume you want the string value so you will need to navigate to that node.

```
XmlNode location = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("plist/dict/key[.='Music Folder']/following-sibling::string[1]")
```

Note that the value is not nested inside the key element but is the following sibling. Given that this appears at the end you could probably get away with:

```
XmlNode location = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("plist/dict/string[last()]")
```

I would explicitly specify the `plist` node in the XPath as it keeps the possible matches to a minimum. Another point to note is that your XPath will likely end up with the underlying technology iterating each node anyway depending on how you structure your expression as some implementations may be able to apply optimisations.

You were close but I see you were mixing up operators and using `::` or `[]`where `/` would be more appropriate. The `::` separates an axis from a node name so `descendants::dict` gets all the descendants of the context node (xmlDocument) named `dict`. The `/` operator is effectively shorthand for `child::`. The `[]` is your filter predicate that narrows a result set.

Comment: Actually, both options work.  I like the first one a bit more, as it is a bit more clear on what the intent is.  Thanks!

Comment: `//string[preceding::key[.="Music Folder"]]/text()` would also work

Comment: @Jahmic you could use following-sibling::* instead of string if you wanted to select either a string or integer node. I agree that the intent is clearer and more robust too

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 best not to select descendants with // especially with apples plist because there may be nested dict nodes and you would end up searching the entire file. +1 for the idea though, plist/dict/string[preceding::key='Music Folder'] reads really nicely

Answer (score 2):

Took 17 millisecondes to get the value of the last node in the document. To test the speed, I created a document containing the `Music Folder` node as last `key` node, and the first 3 nodes listed in your example around 11000 times.

```
string ReadValue(XDocument xDoc, string key)
{
    var node = xDoc.Element("plist")
        .Element("dict")
        .Elements("key")
        .Single(e => e.Value == key)
        .NextNode as XElement;
    return node.Value;
}
```

Comment: This is also pretty good. I may use this in situations where I'm iterating through keys.